# How to optimize SQL Query with INNER JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a fairly large database table that was originally an ACCESS document. It includes different tables for each attribute for the fitment of an auto part. As one can imagine, fitment data contains a lot of specifications and as such, everything is very spread out.

Now building a query to map values from this database is becoming difficult. I have the following query which just seems like it contains too many JOINs... and as I add more, it seems to take a bit longer to run. Is there a better way going about this?

```
 SELECT Import_Values.base_vehicle_id,
    Import_Values.qty,
    Import_Values.part_type_id,
    Import_Values.part_id,
    Import_Values.position_id,
    Import_Values.note,
    Parts.partterminologyname,
    BaseVehicle.YearID,
    Make.MakeName,
    Model.modelname,
    SubModel.SubModelName,
    EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationName,
    EngineVIN.EngineVINName,
    EngineBase.Liter,
    EngineBase.CC,
    EngineBase.CID,
    EngineBase.Cylinders,
    EngineBase.BlockType,
    EngineBase.EngBoreIn,
    EngineBase.EngBoreMetric,
    EngineBase.EngStrokeIn,
    EngineBase.EngStrokeMetric,
    FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeName,
    FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeName,
    FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeName,
    FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignName,
    Aspiration.AspirationName,
    CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeName,
    FuelType.FuelTypeName,
    IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeName,
    Mfr.MfrName,
    EngineVersion.EngineVersion,
    Valves.ValvesPerEngine,
    BedLength.BedLength,
    BedLength.BedLengthMetric,
    BedType.BedTypeName
    FROM 
    Import_Values
    INNER JOIN BaseVehicle 
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=BaseVehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN Parts 
        ON Import_Values.part_type_id=Parts.PartTerminologyID
    INNER JOIN Make
        ON BaseVehicle.MakeID=Make.MakeID
    INNER JOIN Model
        ON BaseVehicle.ModelID=Model.ModelID
    INNER JOIN Vehicle
        ON Import_Values.base_vehicle_id=Vehicle.BaseVehicleID
    INNER JOIN SubModel
        ON Vehicle.SubModelID=SubModel.SubModelID
    INNER JOIN VehicleToEngineConfig
        ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToEngineConfig.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN EngineConfig
        ON VehicleToEngineConfig.EngineConfigID=EngineConfig.EngineConfigID
    INNER JOIN EngineDesignation
        ON EngineConfig.EngineDesignationID=EngineDesignation.EngineDesignationID
    INNER JOIN EngineVIN
        ON EngineConfig.EngineVINID=EngineVIN.EngineVINID
    INNER JOIN EngineBase
        ON EngineConfig.EngineBaseID=EngineBase.EngineBaseID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryConfig
        ON EngineConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID=FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryConfigID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliveryType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliveryTypeID=FuelDeliveryType.FuelDeliveryTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelDeliverySubType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelDeliverySubTypeID=FuelDeliverySubType.FuelDeliverySubTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemControlType
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemControlTypeID=FuelSystemControlType.FuelSystemControlTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelSystemDesign
        ON FuelDeliveryConfig.FuelSystemDesignID=FuelSystemDesign.FuelSystemDesignID
    INNER JOIN Aspiration
        ON EngineConfig.AspirationID=Aspiration.AspirationID
    INNER JOIN CylinderHeadType
        ON EngineConfig.CylinderHeadTypeID=CylinderHeadType.CylinderHeadTypeID
    INNER JOIN FuelType
        ON EngineConfig.FuelTypeID=FuelType.FuelTypeID
    INNER JOIN IgnitionSystemType
        ON EngineConfig.IgnitionSystemTypeID=IgnitionSystemType.IgnitionSystemTypeID
    INNER JOIN Mfr
        ON EngineConfig.EngineMfrID=Mfr.MfrID
    INNER JOIN EngineVersion
        ON EngineConfig.EngineVersionID=EngineVersion.EngineVersionID
    INNER JOIN Valves
        ON EngineConfig.ValvesID=Valves.Valvesid
    INNER JOIN VehicleToBedConfig
        ON Vehicle.VehicleID=VehicleToBedConfig.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN BedConfig
        ON VehicleToBedConfig.BedConfigID=BedConfig.BedConfigID
    INNER JOIN BedLength
        ON BedConfig.BedLengthID=BedLength.BedLengthID
    INNER JOIN BedType
        ON BedConfig.BedTypeID=BedType.BedTypeID
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Define indizes on the columns in your ON clauses. Use [`EXPLAIN SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to see which indizes are used.